# Google Sheets Formula for count under multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'll start off by saying that I'm not very familiar w/ google sheets and its formulas.
How would I go about solving this?

I have two columns: A and B. I want to count the cells under column B under these conditions:

1. look at rows under column B where its corresponding values in column A are not duplicates.

Would this require multiple steps?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(B1:B, REGEXMATCH(B1:B&"", 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(A1:A, A1:A)=1))))))
```

[image]